# Invoke java method from Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I'm looking into Groovy, and I'm trying to bind java objects in groovy and run methods from the script.

Example:

```
public class Toaster{
private int toasted=0;
public Toaster() {
        super();
    }
public void toast(){
     System.out.println(++toasted);
  }
}
```

And in the java main I have:

```
Toaster toaster = new Toaster();
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("toaster", toaster);
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
shell.evaluate("toaster.toast();");
```

This obviously doesn't work, so what do I need to do here to be able to use the java toaster object from groovy?

Comment: `tost()` != `Toast()`

Comment: My typo, I just changed the method names before posting from my actual code for demonstration purposes.

Comment: what exactly is not working? the code you provided should work except the typos...

Comment: @DLabinac: note that the case is still different, is that intentional?

Comment: @DLabinac Class `Toaster` has the method name `Toast` but you call `toaster.toast()` with lowercase on method name. Typo?

Comment: `toast()` != `Toast()` --- Feels like I'm repeating myself.

Comment: As I said, typo. The code in the answer below has it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

your code works fine if you remove all typos...

A.java:

```java
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.lang.Binding;


public class A{
    public static class Toaster{
        private int toasted=0;
        public void toast(){
            System.out.println(++toasted);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        Toaster toaster = new Toaster();
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.setVariable("toaster", toaster);
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
        shell.evaluate("toaster.toast();");   // < prints 1
        shell.evaluate("toaster.toast();");   // < prints 2
        shell.evaluate("toaster.toast();");   // < prints 3
        shell.evaluate("toaster.toast();");   // < prints 4
    }
}
```

compile:

```
javac -cp %GROOVY_HOME%/lib/* A.java
```

run:

```
java -cp %GROOVY_HOME%/lib/*;. A
```

Comment: All I get is:
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: remoteControl.Toaster.toast() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: `remoteControl.Toaster` ?? why again you have `Toaster` capitalized? what is `remoteControl`? the code i gave you is runnable. just copy-paste it into `groovyconsole` and run it.

Comment: I literally copy pasted the code from above into my java project.
remoteControl.Toaster is the class from toaster.
remoteControl is just a random package where I'm experimenting with this.
I'm not using a groovyconsole, I'm coding java with eclipse.

Comment: @DLabinac: the groovy shell string needs not mention the Toaster class by name (with or without package). "toaster" is the variable name that you configure in the binding, not a class name.

Comment: Yes, I know I set the variable name with the binding, but groovy should be aware of its java class structure if it needs to invoke a method in it.

Comment: ok, i converted it to pure java code

Comment: I tried doing exactly as you wrote in the post now, and using the terminal I'd keep getting dependency issues:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class
org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions due to missing dependency ...

I don't know what the issue is, I have downloaded groovy and set up the path. I tried adding the jars manually, but then I'd get:
Error: Could not find or load main class A
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A

I created a new eclipse project, with the exact class, same issue as before:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Comment: There is no jaxb mentioned in code above. You don't need extra libraries except groovy itself. If you are working with maven/gradle - just add groovy-all dependency to your project.

Comment: In eclipse I just added the groovy jar, and it builds it fine, but then I get the groovy.lang.MissingMethodException problem.

Comment: i think you have to edit your question or ask a new one because without stacktrace and the information how you set up the project nobody could help you. again - i provided a fully working example. and chack that you are not mixing `toaster` and `Toaster`. because `toaster.toast()` calls a usual method on object, but `Toaster.toast()` tries to call a static method on class - so you could have missing method issue

Comment: I poked a bit more, and as it seems, the GroovyShell seems not to be able to interface with my project at all. What I do is create a new eclipse project, throw the code example in it, add the groovy jars and run it. There seems to be more to it before it can work, but I don't know what configuration I'm missing for this, because groovy on its own works fine when I evaluate strings.

Comment: you have to ask another question and be more specific. the code above works. and if it does not work for you  - then provide what exactly you are trying to evaluate in groovy and exact error message you have. finally try to reproduce the error in a minimalistic simple project that anybody here could run.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to run it as simple as possible. As I already wrote, I create a new project in eclipse, create the A class, paste the code in it, add the groovy jar dependency and click run. The shell.evaluate method works, it can evaluate groovy expressions, but when it comes to accessing the toaster objects then I get the groovy.lang.MissingMethodException. Accessing/binding Integer variable works fine tho.
There must be something in the groovy setup I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy and java will be compiled to the same bytecode as `.class` file. So, you don't need groovy shell. I am not sure what your arrangement here. But if they both need to be compiled at the same time, I suggest you use Groovy's compiler `groovyc` to compile, so it can recognize Java side of the code.

Comment: Well, I just started looking into Groovy today, the thing I wanted to use it is so I could load scripts from text files which invoke methods and work with objects in my java code.

Comment: @DLabinac You can always use groovyc to compile the groovy code to .class first and put that class files in your classpath. It will work the same as any other java .class .

Comment: That's the exact thing I'm trying to avoid. I want the script to be loaded from a text file and interpreted or runtime compiled, that way I can modify and swap the script with a text editor after the java application has been built.